# Transfering Variable between different files

Tags: c++

I've got `aud.ccp`, `aud.h`, `geist.ccp`, `geist.h`. In `geist.ccp` I've got a variable which needs to get to `aud.ccp`.

If I got:

```
int x = 5;
```

in `geist.ccp`, how can I achieve it, that a `8` gets represented in the console when I use

```
cout << x+y << endl;
```

as well as

```
cin >> y; // ofc I enter 3 here.
```

in `aud.ccp`.

Edit:
I wrote:

```
int x
```

in the public part of geist.h
and I wrote:

```
x = 5;
```

in geist.cpp.
Finaly I wrote

```
extern int x;
```

in aud.cpp

But somehow I do not get the result I want

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable in a public scope of one module:

```
int x;
```

and declare its use in another one:

```
extern int x;
```

Then both modules,  when linked together,  will use the same variable.

It's most conveniently done with the defining declaration (with an optional initializer) placed in a `.cpp` module, and the `extern` declaration put into a `.h` file. Then each module, both the one defining the variable and those importing it, see the same `extern` declaration, which guarantees the declaration is same as an actual definition of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to care about "redefinition x variable Error" in your code.
You can Try this method:

geist.h:

```
#ifndef GEIST_H
#define GEIST_H

int x {5};

#endif
```

geist.cpp:

```
#include "geist.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printname()
{
    cout << "The X value is" << x <<"\n";
}
```

aud.h:

```
#ifndef AUD_H
#define AUD_H

extern int x;
void Add_X_with_User_Desire();

#endif
```

aud.cpp:

```
#include "aud.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Add_X_with_User_Desire()
{
    int y{0};
    cout << "Please Enter an Integer Number: "<< "\n";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "y + x: " << x+y<<"\n";
}
```

and finally main function:

stack59228825.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "aud.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout <<"X variable in main function is:" <<x << "\n";
    Add_X_with_User_Desire();

    x = 10;
    std::cout << "targetVariable in main function is:" << 10 << "\n";
    Add_X_with_User_Desire();

}
```

Comment: Such geist.h doesn't make much sense. If you include it into two or more modules,  the public `x` variable will be declared multiple times, causing linking error. And if you include it just once into geist.cpp then you don't need the .h file - just put its contents into the .cpp file....